# linux/lighttpd: setting umask for webdav?

Tags: linux, lighttpd, webdav, umask

I'm running `lighttpd` on my linux server. I have set up `webdav`, and I want to set the umask to a specific value *only* for the `webdav` site, and not for any other sites running under my `lighttpd` server. Is there any way to tell `webdav` under `lighttpd` to use a specific umask?

Note that I am using the standard debian build for `lighttpd` and `lighttpd-mod-webdav` from `apt`. I would prefer to not build any of this from source, if at all possible.

Here is the configuration I'm using for the `webdav` site ...

```
server.username  = "www-data"
server.groupname = "www-data"

[... etc. ...]

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/webdav/" {
  webdav.activate                = "enable"
  webdav.is-readonly             = "disable"
  webdav.sqlite-db-name          = "/var/www/etc/lighttpd.webdav.db"
  auth.backend                   = "htpasswd"
  auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/var/www/etc/.htaccess"
  auth.require                   = (
    "" => ( "method"  => "basic",
            "realm"   => "Restricted.",
            "require" => "valid-user"
          )           
  )
}
```

Also ...

```
# /usr/sbin/lighttpd -V
lighttpd/1.4.35 (ssl) - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Aug  2 2016 09:50:21

Event Handlers:

    + select (generic)
    + poll (Unix)
    - rt-signals (Linux 2.4+)
    + epoll (Linux 2.6)
    - /dev/poll (Solaris)
    - eventports (Solaris)
    - kqueue (FreeBSD)
    - libev (generic)

Network handler:

    + linux-sendfile
    - freebsd-sendfile
    - solaris-sendfilev
    + writev
    + write
    - mmap support

Features:

    + IPv6 support
    + zlib support
    + bzip2 support
    + crypt support
    + SSL Support
    + PCRE support
    + mySQL support
    + LDAP support
    - memcached support
    + FAM support
    + LUA support
    + xml support
    + SQLite support
    + GDBM support
```

Thank you very much for any insights or suggestions.

Comment: Hmm ... could `lua` somehow be used to set the umask for this site?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution: You can run two instances of lighttpd, and have one proxy back to the other one.  The backend can be started up using a different umask (and even run under different user account) for handling webdav.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be impossible without modifying `lighttpd-mod-webdav`. I will work on that, and I am giving up on trying to solve this using standard `lighttpd` facilities.